# TypeError when importing Python's decimal module

Tags: python

What causes the TypeError when importing the decimal module?

```
[Michael@devserver MyScripts]$ cat decTest.py
from decimal import *

#item = Decimal( 0.70 )
[Michael@devserver MyScripts]$ python3.3 decTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decTest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from decimal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/decimal.py", line 433, in <module>
    import threading
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 6, in <module>
    from time import sleep as _sleep
  File "/var/www/python/ineasysteps/MyScripts/time.py", line 3, in <module>
    today = datetime.today()
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.time)
[Michael@devserver MyScripts]$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have in your own folder a file named "time.py", which conflicts with the built-in time module.  Notice how in the stack trace it shows the threading module needing to import "time".

Rename your "time.py" to something that is not the same name as a built-in module.

Comment: Thanks Bryan,  I am obviously very new to Python.  I now see how decimal imports threading which imports time.  Will Python always attempt to use the file in the current directory?  How do I prevent this?

Comment: @user1032531: see https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path, or search for "[python] module search path" here on stackoverflow.

Comment: So `time` is not a `built-in module`?  Otherwise, it should have been used per `When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:`

Comment: No, `time` is not a built-in module, though it's part of the standard library. It's arguably a subtle distinction.

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  Going to take a little time getting used to :)

Comment: I could envision having these errors all the time when I import a standard library module.  Is there some sort of strategy to prevent them?

Comment: @user1032531: stackoverlow isn't designed for discussions. If you have a completely separate question, first do some research on your own. If you can't find a suitable answer, click the "Ask Question" button.